How to colorize Android Studio Text Files? The ones you add by Menu: File -> New -> File. Question about Editor Configuration
This not a question about Coding is about the Android Studio itself.
I added some files in the Project for taking Notes for example "To Do" tasks, and features too add to the application.
I would like to colorize some of the lines, or phrases in the "Notes".
Is there a way to do something about that?
I notice that when I write the word "todo" the line turns green-ish.
Are there more words like that or how can I define them so I can use them as Tags to make the lines of a particular color?
